# TSQL DISTINCT RECORD COUNT

Tags: t-sql, count, distinct

---

I am using SSMS 2008 and am trying to get a distinct count of Event_names from my table.  But instead, it is returning count = 1 when there are actually 2 records and other invalid values.  What I want is the total count / consumer for their number of distinct event_names they are part of.  Also, some of the Event Counts for the same consumer are different.  But I want one distinct count / consumer.  Here is a portion of the data returned by my invalid query:

### consumer    Program Enrollment Date event_name  Event_Ct

```
B, Tiffany  2010-09-27 12:00:00.000 Comprehensive Clinical Assessment   1
B, Tiffany  2010-09-27 00:00:00.000 Telemedicine Comprehensive Clinical Assessment  1
B, Nickolas Tyan    2010-12-07 15:00:00.000 Comprehensive Clinical Assessment   1
B, Nickolas Tyan    2010-12-07 00:00:00.000 Telemedicine Comprehensive Clinical Assessment  1
B, Jack 2011-06-13 08:30:00.000 Comprehensive Clinical Assessment   1
B, Jack 2011-01-03 00:00:00.000 Medication Management   1
B, Victoria Lynn    2010-11-10 00:00:00.000 Telemedicine Comprehensive Clinical Assessment  3
B, Victoria Lynn    2010-12-28 00:00:00.000 Telemedicine Psychiatric Assessment 3
B, Victoria Lynn    2011-01-07 00:00:00.000 Telemedicine Psychiatric Progress Note  2
B, Victoria Lynn    2011-02-08 00:00:00.000 Telemedicine Psychiatric Progress Note  2
```

And here is the T-SQL I used for the above:

```
SELECT consumer, [Program Enrollment Date], event_name, [Program Quarter]
INTO #INITIATIONS
FROM #consumer_initiations   
WHERE consumer IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT Consumer 
FROM #consumer_initiations
GROUP BY Consumer 
HAVING Count(DISTINCT event_name) > 1)
ORDER BY consumer, event_name

SELECT A.consumer, A.[Program Enrollment Date], A.event_name, count(A.event_name)
FROM #INITIATIONS A 
JOIN #INITIATIONS B ON A.consumer = B.consumer AND A.event_name <> B.event_name AND A.[Program Enrollment Date] <> B.[Program Enrollment Date]
GROUP BY A.consumer, A.event_name, a.[Program Enrollment Date]
```

I also tried this query, which returned correct counts for consumers with only 2 records, but for those with > 2 records, it returned too high of counts:

```
SELECT A.consumer, count(A.event_name)
FROM #INITIATIONS A 
JOIN #INITIATIONS B ON A.consumer = B.consumer AND A.event_name <> B.event_name AND A.[Program Enrollment Date] <> B.[Program Enrollment Date]
GROUP BY A.consumer
```

Thanks to Chris, here is the solution that worked:

```
Select I.consumer, [Program Enrollment Date], event_name, countPerConsumer.[Number of Events] 
From #INITIATIONS i 
Join (Select Consumer, count(distinct event_name) as [Number of Events] From #INITIATIONS GROUP BY Consumer) countPerConsumer  
    on countPerConsumer.Consumer
```

= i.consumer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've grasped what your trying to do.  If not I appolgize.  something like this should help you:

```
Select consumer, [Program Enrollment Date], event_name, countPerConsumer.[Number of Events]
From #INITIATIONS i
Join (Select Consumer, count(distinct event_name) as [Number of Events] 
        group by Consumer)countPerConsumer 
    on countPerConsumber.consumer = i.consumer
```

the idea is your joining a table built on the fly of a count of distinct events for each consumer.  you should be able to keep the piece where you build #INITIATIONS and just replace the last query with the above.  hope this helps.

Comment: This did it after slight modifications.  I had to add GROUP BY statement and correct a typo.  I am revising my description to show solution.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about the typos.  Im glade I was able to help.